# SSRS 2012: Cannot add multi value parameter '?' for dataset XYZ because it is not supported by the data extension

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, multivalue

Scenario:  I am working with a Firebird database (somewhat similar to MySQL) connected to Microsoft SSRS 2012 via ODBC connection manager.

I have a huge stored procedure (which I am not supposed to modify at all) given by our client. The stored procedure has a parameter - Parameter X filtering Column X (integer datatype); when I pass values to  Parameter X - say 1,2,3,4... individually, I am able to run the report correctly in SSRS.

However, when I try to pass a string of values - (1,2,3,4...)  - i.e. (by checking) 'Allow multiple values' for this Parameter X (text datatype) in SSRS Report Parameter Properties box, I get this error -

> 'Cannot add multi value parameter '?' for dataset XYZ because it is
>   not supported by the data extension.   (XYZ is the main dataset for this report)

The values 1,2,3 are passed as input from *another dataset (PQR).*

How can I pass multiple input values (1,2,3,...) to Parameter X from this PQR dataset ?

### As I have mentioned, I cannot modify the PSQL Firebird stored procedure (main dataset XYZ) at all. The procedure reads something like this for filtering Column_X:

```
WHERE       :Parameter_X    CONTAINING   Column_X
```

---

Now   if :Parameter_X = 1 or 2 or 3 individually passed from dataset PQR, SSRS report works fine.

If          :Parameter_X = (1 ,2, 3, ....) multi values passed from dataset PQR, SSRS report throws the above error.

I can modify the dataset PQR, but not the main dataset XYZ.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Figured out:

Go to the main dataset (XYZ) of the report;
In the Dataset Properties, go to the Parameters tab.
In the Parameter Value column for the particular parameter in question,
overwrite [@ParameterX]  with :

=Join(Parameters!ParameterX.Value,",")   

My Input has to be   (1 2 3  .....) for ParameterX from the dataset PQR;

This will be passed as  (1,2,3,....) with the Join keyword; and multi select is allowed without errors now.

The datatype for ParameterX in SSRS must be Text only.

This is the workaround WITHOUT modifying the stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

Join(Parameters!ParameterX.Value,",")  still works. In my case it was using OLE DB connection type instead of regular ORACLE in Report Manager.

It seems OLE DB could not parse Join(Parameters!ParameterX.Value,",") .